# How to push data to multiple clients

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, lua, coronasdk

I need to build a server to an application who's client side is written in Lua using Corona SDK (application for mobile smartphones and tablets), and server side in .NET.
I have thousands of clients who I need to push data to in a form of XML file or JSON array, every few hours or daily. (Not notifications. Data that needs to reach the application directly and trigger certain actions).

Is there a way to push the data **without** WCF?

The only other way I found was SignalR, but my client isn't a web browser so I ruled it out.

In my searches I found in stackoverflow a question with a recommendation to push data using 0MQ (http://zeromq.org/), I just found it hard to understand if it fits my needs, can I queue so many clients in one server and delay the answer a few hours or days?

Other recommendations would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Basically, you can use any message queue (there are a lot of them, 0mq is just one example.) I used to work with AMQ and there you had an option either to send messages to a single client, and then the messages will be queued up until the client dequeued them, or to send messages to multiple clients but then the messages are not queued so if a customer is not listening at the moment the message is sent to the message server, then it will miss the message.

Comment: You can use SignalR out of web browser also. Web browser is not a requirement for SignalR. In early days of SignalR we used it in our iOS native app without any client library. You can easily implement Ajax long polling Transport in any programming language with just a few http calls. At server side you can use signalr server library as usual. You can go through any SignalR client library code and implement the long pooling part. We implemented that in iOS native app by just watching all the calls in fiddler when a web browser app is configured to use SignalR Long pooling.